# How to center a div with Bootstrap2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

I tried like all combinations:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span7 offset5"> box </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span7 offset5"> box </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

changed span and offset numbers...

But I cant get a simple box perfectly centered on a page :(

I just want a 6-column-wide box centered...

---

edit:

did it with

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="login-container">
    <div class="span8 offset2">
       box
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the box is too wide, is there any way I can do it with span7 ?

`span7 offset2` gives extra padding to the left `span7 offset3` extra padding to the right...

Comment: Are you looking to center a box horizontally on the page? Because the `container` class already does that, thought you might be looking to center a smaller box. Or are you looking to center a box both horizontally and vertically on the page?

Comment: a box thing you say?
. . . .here in developer world we call that a div

Comment: What version of Bootstrap were you using? it should be reflected in the title as people looking this up will end up here and see outdated code.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

besides shrinking the div itself to the size you want, by reducing span size like so... `class="span6 offset3"`, `class="span4 offset4"`, etc... something as simple as `style="text-align: center"` on the div could have the effect you're looking for

you can't use span7 with any set offset and get the span centered on the page (Because total spans = 12)

Comment: Consider Zuhaib Ali's answer. text-align: center doesn't work for centering elements within a <div>.  The offset* class isn't truly centering components.  It is merely creating the illusion of centering.  You can verify this by resizing the window and seeing that the components do not remain centered.  When you apply Zuhaib Ali's method, the components stay centered.

Comment: Instead of adding inline styling (style="text-align:center"), add the class "center-block" and get centred content within your centred div.

Comment: col-md-4 or col-lg-4 is equal a margin: 0 auto; ?

Answer (score 165):

Bootstrap's spans are floated to the left. All it takes to center them is override this behavior. I do this by adding this to my stylesheet:

```
.center {
     float: none;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
```

If you have this class defined, just add it to the span and you're good to go.

```
<div class="span7 center"> box </div>
```

Note that this custom center class must be defined *after* the bootstrap css. You could use `!important` but that isn't recommended.

Comment: I'm using Rails, so I just want to point out that in application.css, add `*= require bootstrap.min` **before** `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree`

Comment: This didn't work for me, but adding `display: table` seemed to fix it

Answer (score 35):

Bootstrap3 has the `.center-block` class that you can use. It is defined as

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-center).

Answer (score 21):

If you want to go full-bootstrap (and not the auto left/right way) you need a pattern that will fit within 12 columns e.g. 2 blanks, 8 content, 2 blanks. That's what this setup will do.
It only covers the *-md-* variants, I tend to snap it to full size for small by adding col-xs-12

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
     box
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is that a valid way of centering divs in boostrap?

Comment: The content of the div is not centered, but the div itself is.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you just wanted to center align a single container.
The bootstrap framework might be overcomplicating that one example, you could have just had a standalone div with your own styling, something like:

```
<div class="login-container">
  <!-- Your Login Form -->
</div>
```

and style:

```
.login-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px; /* Whatever exact width you are looking for (not bound by preset bootstrap widths) */
}
```

That should work fine if you are nested somewhere within a bootstrap `.container` div.

Answer (score 3):

add the class centercontents

```
/** Center the contents of the element **/
.centercontents {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ZuhaibAli code kind of work for me but I changed it a little bit:

I created a new class in css

```
.center {
     float: none;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
```

then the div become

```
<div class="center col-md-6"></div>
```

I added col-md-6 for the width of the div itself which in this situation meant the div is half the size, there are 1 -12 col md in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guidance https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

Use `.center-block`

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the div in a parent div with class `row` then add style `margin:0 auto;` to the div

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="margin: 0 auto;">center</div>
</div>
```