# Problems with footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that I want to auto center the content of with:

```css
position: absolute 
left: 50%
margin-left: -1/2 of width.
```

This works but when I use `position: absolute` it's like my footer suddenly doesn't see the content and floats up. I tried using this [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer),
but it does not work for me. Here is a link to the page without the sticky footer and auto center removed: http://cashforcarsanywhere.com/how-it-works/

Any help would be appreciated.

I have no experience with JavaScript or jQuery so please try to limit answers to CSS, HTML.

Comment: can you post our css and html or something like jsfiddle for show us the issue..

Comment: Which content do you want centered? `div.span8`?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. What portion of the code do I use?

Comment: try to use css to auto center of a page. `.selector{ margin: 0 auto; }` but don't forget to give it `width`. -> `.selector{ width: 80%; }` *sample

Comment: #howitworkscontent   is what i want centered.

Comment: Aldi, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Here's another (pretty simple) solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554724/how-do-i-center-a-bootstrap-div-with-a-spanx-class#9554800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `position:absolute` will remove that element from the document flow. So, it will no longer push your footer down.

I had success with the CSS below.

Please note that you have several cascading definitions for `div.span8`. Be sure to remove *all* float and width settings. Actually, I just removed the entire `span8` class from that `div`.

```
div.span8 {
  // remove all float and width settings.
  // (I just removed the entire class "span8" from this `div`.)
}


#howitworkscontent {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 15px auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  /*float: left;*/
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5WFNW/

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by hustlerinc, and since the OP is trying to use bootstrap responsive, it would probably be better to use a bootstrap class instead of `width:800px`. However, as bootstrap's `.span` classes include `float:left`, you will need to also set `float:none`.

Comment: showdev, thank you so much. It worked beautifully. This will work on other pages as well?

Comment: Yes, if you use the same concept shown here. However, keep in mind that there might be a reason that div has a class of `span8`. I'm not very familiar with bootstrap, so make sure you know what you're changing.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[#footer on page bottom](http://jsbin.com/ofagud/1/edit)**</kbd>

**Essencials:**

```
<div id="footer">
   <p>This is some #footer content</p>
</div>
```

```
#footer{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; /* abs. el. loose width, so regain */
  bottom:0px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  background:#bada55;
}
```

---

<kbd>**[#footer on page bottom with Centered Content](http://jsbin.com/ofagud/1/edit)**</kbd>

**Essencials:**

```
<div id="footer">
  <div>
     <p>This is some Centered #footer content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#footer{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; /* abs. el. loose width, so regain */
  bottom:0px;
  background:#bada55;
}

#footer > div{
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  padding:20px 15px; /* padding here, now #footer is only a marionette :) */
  background:#cf5;
}
```

---

<kbd>**[Example with page content](http://jsbin.com/ofagud/4/edit)**</kbd>

**Essencials:**

```
<div id="page">
  <p>This is some Centered #page content my 100px padding bottom will prevent the content to end up behing the #footer applying properly the vertical window scrollbars once I touch the very page bottom.</p>
</div>  

<div id="footer">
  <div>
     <p>This is some Centered #footer content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#page{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:600px;
  padding:20px 15px 100px;
  background:#eee; /* BG is just for example, avoid BG on this element, rather create an inner one*/
}

#footer{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; /* abs. el. loose width, so regain */
  bottom:0px;
  background:#bada55;
}

#footer > div{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:20px 15px; /* padding here, now #footer is only a marionette :) */
  width: 600px;
  background:#cf5;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for using bootstrap is that you dont need all that messy css, use it to your advantage.

**Edit**: I took a closer look in your code, this is your solution.
Change `<div class="span8">` into `<div class="span8 offset2">` and it will be perfectly centered.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: This centers the text, but does not seem to center the `div` element.

Comment: Depends where you put it, it's about the hierarchy of the site. I didn't take too close of a look at his code but I suppose <div class="row text-center"> should do it and then the text inside other divs that dont inherit text-center.

Comment: We're talking about centering a `<div>` though, not the text inside the `<div>`.

Comment: It centers div's too, buttons any element within the text-center div. Anyway I edited my answer to fit his code.

Comment: But only `inline` elements. Unless you set `display:inline` on the target `div`, `text-align:center` on its parent will not center it. http://jsfiddle.net/JucP2/

Comment: The `offset2` class does not center it either: `.offset2 { margin-left: 230px; }`

Comment: It would've if you didn't mess up bootstraps original code. Remove anything you did, add that class and it will work. Refer to the docs if you dont trust me. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: `offset2` relates to the grid system and offsetting columns, not centering. It might *look* more centered, but it just has a left margin. `Move columns to the right using .offset* classes. Each class increases the left margin of a column by a whole column. For example, .offset4 moves .span4 over four columns.`

Comment: Which is exactly what the OP was asking for. My solution was 1 word to center his span8 on any device, any page width. The way bootstrap recommends. Going in and changing css isn't needed, with your solution it will look messed up on devices below 800px.

Comment: The OP may not be using bootstrap-responsive to its full potential. However, given the site the OP provided, `offset2` does not work: http://i.imgur.com/7RT6isc.jpg Also, see TrueLifeCoder's comment to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382970/how-to-center-a-box-thing-with-bootstrap#9419480

Comment: True, to accommodate smaller devices, you could remove the `width:800px` and set a span class (`span8`) instead. But you still have to "unfloat" the `span8`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554724/how-do-i-center-a-bootstrap-div-with-a-spanx-class#9554800

Comment: Only if you're going to go against bootstraps own recommendations. They tell you to put an offset, not margin: 0px auto. span8 means so much more than just the width, read about their grid and use of columns before commenting on it, I use it in all my projects. Anyway I dropped it, so should you.