# Centering Text In a Div: Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center my text in a div (vertically and horizontally), but I am using the bootstrap3 grid system so I can't seem to find an applicable answer. Most answers that I found require a table.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-4">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-4">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-4">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382970/how-to-center-a-box-thing-with-bootstrap

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2013, you should consider using the absolute centering method.

Add to your CSS:

```
.hv-center-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.hv-center {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px; /* height must be set to work, percentages will work */
}
```

Add class `.hv-center` to any element that you want both horizontal and vertical centering. Then wrap the element around an outer div `.hv-center-wrap`.

(`vertical-align: middle` will not center the text vertically. That only works for specific elements, not divs.)

Comment: I think this works. but it's really difficult to calibrate the width and height.

Comment: It's a tradeoff, but personally I think this solution is much better than table-oriented ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That only centers horizontally. Let's say that each div has a height of 250px. How can I center the text vertically as well?

Comment: Edited to add vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>

</div>
```

It is better if you create CSS class- like

```
   .cAlign{
        text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle
    }
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-4 cAlign">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-4 cAlign">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-4 cAlign">
        This is the text that I want to center...
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That only centers horizontally. How can I center the text vertically as well?

Comment: Also your CSS class is unnccessary as bootstrap already comes with that class .text-center

Comment: @Rhs see my edit, you can use the vertical-align:middle to center text vertically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249359/text-vertical-align-in-a-div see this link to align vertical