# With HTMl5 how do I center a embedded YouTube video and center it?

Tags: html, youtube, center

I tried things like text align and center tags... Can anyone help?

Thanks - Max

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I align YouTube embedded video in the center in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433616/how-can-i-align-youtube-embedded-video-in-the-center-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS property to your iframe and:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLqbLL39/)

```
iframe {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/DTQTC290UY8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> I put that in my index.html and I put your code in my main.css class.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the center tag. Leave all the styling to the CSS.

Did you try setting the left and right margins to auto?

Something like:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Edit: I was able to center a YouTube video by making the CSS for the iFrame set its width, set its display type to block, and set the horizontal margins to auto. Here's what my code looks like.

```
iframe {
    width: 560px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```